# Pywin32 fails in embedded installation with Python 3.9

Tags: pywin32, python-embedding

I am trying to install pywin32 in a Python 3.9 x64 embedded environment (on Windows 10). Installation works, but import fails.

Steps to reproduce:

```
mkdir embed
unzip python-3.9.0-embed-amd64.zip embed
python -m pip install --target embed pywin32

cd embed
python
import win32api
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the library to a different path helps:

```
mkdir embed
unzip python-3.9.0-embed-amd64.zip embed
python -m pip install --target embed\lib\site-packages pywin32

cd embed
python
import site
site.addsitedir("lib/site-packages")

import win32api
```

I have an open issue for this: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1618